# Disable Briefing Notifications on Galaxy S8

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-8

It seems once or twice a day, I get some Briefing notifications on my Galaxy S8. The icon for these notifications appears similar to Flipboard, though I don't have Flipboard installed as a standalone application.

I believe these notifications may instead be coming from Bixby, which appears to use Flipboard for its news feed. Right now, I'm really not interested in using Bixby or its Briefings. I have the Bixby Home Screen turned off, and would probably even disable its dedicated hardware button if I could do it without rooting.

However, I can't find any options to disable notifications from Bixby nor any options related to turning off Flipboard/Briefing alerts. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

Bixby --> scroll down till you see News --> click the 3 little dots on the right and disable notifications